# Was the recent spate of military coups in Africa done so with either the overt or covert support of the USA?

Tags: united-states, military, africa, coup, african-union

The Intercept has reported that since 2008, at least eight successful military coups have occurred in Africa led by US trained soldiers: Guinea, Mauritanea and the Gambia, and also three times each in Burkina Faso and Mali.

Three of these countries have been suspended by the African Union: Burkina Faso, Guinea and Mali with Ghana's president, Nana Akufo-Addo saying:

> The resurgance of coup d'etats in our region is in direct violation of our democratic tenets and represents a direct threat to peace, security and stability in West Africa.

**Q. Did these coups occur with the direct assistance of the USA, whether overt or covert?**

Comment: Coupled with the immediate [follow-up question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73015/were-recent-possibly-us-backed-coups-in-africa-responsible-for-the-poor-suppor), I believe both are asked to promote a political cause.

Comment: US trained soldiers... the US trains a LOT of people. There is a difference between US trained and US backed, supported, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I can't be bothered to look at all the other "recent" allegations that span 14 years, but it's doubtful the US backed the Mali coup since they newly installed military government [kicked](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/01/31/africa/mali-french-ambassador-expelled-intl/index.html) the French out (seemingly after they pestered them with returning to democracy) and [invited](https://www.africanews.com/2022/05/03/sergei-lavrov-wagner-in-mali-and-libya-on-a-commercial-basis//) the Russians in.

It's true that the 2020 coup leader had some kind of training in the US, but that's not saying much, really. Goita [was](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/mali-coup-leader-was-trained-by-us-special-operations-forces/2020/08/21/33153fbe-e31c-11ea-82d8-5e55d47e90ca_story.html) also disillusioned with the lack/pace of success against the Islamists. Apparently he thought the Russian playbook (Syria etc.) might work better. The US [military] also publicly disapproved of the coup, when it happened:

> “The act of mutiny in Mali is strongly condemned and inconsistent with U.S. military training and education,” said Marine Corps Lt. Col. Anton T. Semelroth, a Pentagon spokesman.
>
> The Malian military will receive no more support from the United States until further review, he added.

Answer (score -2):

This is just a tentative answer since I'm just begun looking at this - why else would I ask a question?

*Foreign Policy* in Feb 2022 had an [article](https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/02/03/burkina-faso-coup-us-security-assistance-terrorism-military/) where they write:

> Since 2009, the USA has been supporting Burkino Faso's military with funding, weapons and training as part of Washington's post 9-11 counter-terrorism efforts. That support, while not directly responsible for ladt weeks coup, helpwd lay the groundwork for the country's increased militarism - and ultimately the coup it produced.

The *New York Times* also reported that the American Green Berets were training soldiers in Guinea when their charges left in the middle of a training session to mount a coup deposing the 83 year old president, Alpha Conde. Some of the green berets were videoed celebrating - which caused serious embarassment to the US government.

Comment: (Not my DV.) Time will tell if this is a facade or not, but the new Burkina Faso government, despite its military leader, actually seems much more inclined to negotiate with the Islamists
https://www.thenewhumanitarian.org/interview/2022/04/27/dialogue-with-jihadists-interview-with-burkina-fasos-minister-of-reconciliation So drawing too many parallels based on "militarism" might not be all that warranted.

Comment: And I couldn't find where the NYT says *the Americans* were celebrating https://www.nytimes.com/2021/09/10/world/africa/guinea-coup-americans.html OTOH, it seems there was plenty of celebration from the locals following the coup https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-58461971

Comment: It seems [this](https://www.theafricareport.com/127544/were-us-soldiers-really-involved-in-guineas-latest-coup/) is the video in question, where the US soldiers are seen smiling as they are driven through the (celebrating) crowd. That's not a lot of celebration on the part of the US soldiers, IMHO. In fact, Stars and Stripes was so "embarrassed" that they posted an article on the video themselves https://www.stripes.com/branches/army/2021-09-10/green-berets-africom-guinea-coup-2836178.html

Comment: I know little about Guinea politics, but it seems that Conde changing the constitution to allow a 3rd term for himself was apparently not too popular at least with some locals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%932020_Guinean_protests